# Windows Server 2019 can't see shared disk from Linux Centos 9

Tags: linux, centos, mount, nfs

> Centos ip: 192.168.227.123
> Win: 192.168.227.121
> Device: /dev/mapper/mpatha1
> mountpoint: /nfsserver

[image: /etc/exports config]

[image: /etc/fstab]

Mount:
[image: Mount]

Tried 100 different things on Windows, such as disabling hibernation etc, nfs services and other stuff are installed and running on win. Also i have mounted this disk but its empty

Mounted, but empty:
[image: Mounted, but empty]

Comment: Sorry, but i dont know how to edit this thing to look better , this edit window is weird

Comment: If you are trying to map a folder in Linux from the Windows Server, install Samba in Linux and set it up.

Comment: Was the export established before or after the volume was mounted? What happens if you unexport /nfsserver with `exportfs -u`, then re-export it? (And, are you required to use NFS? Generally Windows prefers SMBv3, which might even perform better.)

Comment: Yeah, i am required to use NFS

Comment: Unexported it and exported it again, nothing